# # or ## for language name/program size

Tags: support

I've seen people use `#` (h1) and `##` (h2) on the language name and program size in their answers, but is one of them considered better?

Comment: Note: Try it Online produces `#` when generating answer headers, which may be why `#` is more common.

Comment: Seems like this is a duplicate of http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1200/62101

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Back in the day, HTML style guides told you to use only one `<h1>` in a page. Given the semantics of a StackExchange page, that should be the question title. Therefore we old fogies consider `##` better.

Nowadays some people consider that advice antiquated. I leave it to them to say whether they consider `#` and `##` equally good or whether they have arguments either way.

Answer (score 8):

As one of the users of `#`, here's my rationale.

1. Markdown gives you a handy way of grouping your post into (sub)sections using `#`, `##`, and `###`. If you use `#` for the header, you still get sections and subsections. If you use `##`, you only get sections.
2. When writing Markdown, I don't really consider the HTML is generates. If `<h1>` is not meant to be used in answers, `#` should generate `<h2>` elements. I can't do anything about this.
3. Having multiple `<h1>` elements in one page is valid HTML. It used to be a bad idea, but [that's no longer true for HTML5](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/the-truth-about-multiple-h1-tags-in-the-html5-era--webdesign-16824).

Comment: Agreed. Some people write `<h1>` in their answers, but I use `#`, which isn't HTML, it's markdown.

Comment: Regarding point 3, that article is wrong about the use of H1 in HTML5. There was a time when the draft spec allowed multiple H1s, but they eventually [scrapped that idea](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=19741). The current recommendation is you "should use headings of the appropriate rank for the section's nesting level." I agree with your other points though.